# Please help me find the syntax error in my code

Tags: python, syntax

`print(n1 "+" n2 "="add(n1,n2))`

This is the line that I can't understand my mistake.

Comment: Did you mean: `print(n1, " + ", n2, "=", add(n1,n2))`?

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it only consists of typos

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(n1,"+",n2,"=",add(n1,n2))
```

Comma delimited values by a space.